# Extracting complex words from paragraph

Tags: python

I am trying to extract a group of text from a paragraph that was read from a four column pdf  table.

this is the the raw text

```
  015536159/6630     CAGE Contract Number Quantity Unit Cost AWD Date 32YK1 SPE2DH19P0522 22.000 1394.13000 20190102 32YK1 SPE2DH18P1630 21.000 1356.41000 20180604 74YZ3  SPE2DH18P1184 15.000 1282.50000 20180314 32YK1 SPE2DH17V1630 16.000 1335.91000 20170214 58837 SPE2DH16V2501 17.000 1369.00000 20160601 32YK1 SPE2DH16M0463 13.000 1358.20000 20151125  CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE       
                                                           CONTINUATION SHEET     REFERENCE NO. OF DOCUMENT BEING CONTINUED: SPE2DH-19-T-6601     PAGE 4 OF 22 PAGES        SECTION A  Procurement History for NSN/FSC:015536159/6630  CAGE Contract Number  Quantity Unit Cost AWD Date              32YK1 S$ DH16M0068 32YK1 SPE2DH14V3122 32YK1 S$ DH14V2252 32YK1 SPE2DH14V0165     58837 SPM2DH13V1222 08576 SPM2DH13M0509 58837 SPM2DH12V0342 08576 SPM2DH12M0490 08576 SPM2DH11V1261 3BSP4 SPM2DSO8MA800 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M6542 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5128 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5127 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5125  18.000 1462.05000 20151005 12.000 1246.39000 20140918 9.000 1246.39000 20140711 10.000 1246.39000 20131223 12.000 1258.00000 20130724 15.000 1100.09000 20121205 27.000 1200.00000 20111223 34.000 1057.77000 20111202 3.000 1057.77000 20110727  2.000 947.16000 20080721 100.000 947.16000 20080323 2.000 947.16000 20080227 2.000 947.16000 20080227 2.000 947.16000 20080225  CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE       
             CONTINUATION SHEET REFERENCE NO. OF DOCUMENT BEING CONTINUED:  SPE2DH-19-T-6601        PAGE 5 OF 22 PAGES        SECTION B
```

I want to only extract this texts

```
 32YK1 SPE2DH19P0522 22.000 1394.13000 20190102 32YK1 SPE2DH18P1630 21.000 1356.41000 20180604 74YZ3  SPE2DH18P1184 15.000 1282.50000 20180314 32YK1 SPE2DH17V1630 16.000 1335.91000 20170214 58837 SPE2DH16V2501 17.000 1369.00000 20160601 32YK1 SPE2DH16M0463 13.000 1358.20000 20151125
  32YK1 S$ DH16M0068 32YK1 SPE2DH14V3122 32YK1 S$ DH14V2252 32YK1 SPE2DH14V0165     58837 SPM2DH13V1222 08576 SPM2DH13M0509 58837 SPM2DH12V0342 08576 SPM2DH12M0490 08576 SPM2DH11V1261 3BSP4 SPM2DSO8MA800 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M6542 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5128 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5127 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5125  18.000 1462.05000 20151005 12.000 1246.39000 20140918 9.000 1246.39000 20140711 10.000 1246.39000 20131223 12.000 1258.00000 20130724 15.000 1100.09000 20121205 27.000 1200.00000 20111223 34.000 1057.77000 20111202 3.000 1057.77000 20110727  2.000 947.16000 20080721 100.000 947.16000 20080323 2.000 947.16000 20080227 2.000 947.16000 20080227 2.000 947.16000 20080225
```

I have tried many different methods like creating an array of unwanted words and removing them from the paragraph using this code

```
 filterWords= [preNSN,FSC,NSN,'NSN/FSC:'+NSN,'Cage','Contract','Number','Quantity','Unit','Cost','AWD','Date','CONTINUED', 'SECTION', 'Procurement','history','For','on','Next','Page','Continuation','Sheet','Reference','of','Document','Being','CONTINUED','pages','SECTION']


 regex = r'\b(?:' + '|'.join(filterWords) + r')\s*\b'
 filteredHistory = re.sub(regex, '', history, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

the problem with that is sometimes the not all unwanted words are removed. is there a way to target just the desired words instead of removing unwanted ones?

Comment: There are e.g. `re.search` and `re.findall` for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the structure of your documents are similar, you could try to parse the text in between markers.

Maybe you will need to stare at your data for a while to see its structure.

From the sample provided, this works:

```
raw = """  015536159/6630     CAGE Contract Number Quantity Unit Cost AWD Date 32YK1 SPE2DH19P0522 22.000 1394.13000 20190102 32YK1 SPE2DH18P1630 21.000 1356.41000 20180604 74YZ3  SPE2DH18P1184 15.000 1282.50000 20180314 32YK1 SPE2DH17V1630 16.000 1335.91000 20170214 58837 SPE2DH16V2501 17.000 1369.00000 20160601 32YK1 SPE2DH16M0463 13.000 1358.20000 20151125  CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE       
                                                           CONTINUATION SHEET     REFERENCE NO. OF DOCUMENT BEING CONTINUED: SPE2DH-19-T-6601     PAGE 4 OF 22 PAGES        SECTION A  Procurement History for NSN/FSC:015536159/6630  CAGE Contract Number  Quantity Unit Cost AWD Date              32YK1 S$ DH16M0068 32YK1 SPE2DH14V3122 32YK1 S$ DH14V2252 32YK1 SPE2DH14V0165     58837 SPM2DH13V1222 08576 SPM2DH13M0509 58837 SPM2DH12V0342 08576 SPM2DH12M0490 08576 SPM2DH11V1261 3BSP4 SPM2DSO8MA800 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M6542 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5128 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5127 3BSP4 SPM2DS08M5125  18.000 1462.05000 20151005 12.000 1246.39000 20140918 9.000 1246.39000 20140711 10.000 1246.39000 20131223 12.000 1258.00000 20130724 15.000 1100.09000 20121205 27.000 1200.00000 20111223 34.000 1057.77000 20111202 3.000 1057.77000 20110727  2.000 947.16000 20080721 100.000 947.16000 20080323 2.000 947.16000 20080227 2.000 947.16000 20080227 2.000 947.16000 20080225  CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE       
             CONTINUATION SHEET REFERENCE NO. OF DOCUMENT BEING CONTINUED:  SPE2DH-19-T-6601        PAGE 5 OF 22 PAGES        SECTION B """

start = '32YK1'

result = []
for line in raw.splitlines():
    res = []
    seen = False
    for elt in line.split():
        if elt == start:      # <- start recording tokens past (and including) this one.
            seen = True
        if seen:
            res.append(elt)
    result.append(res[:-4])   # <- remove the last 4 unneeded tokens using slicing

for res in result:
    print(' '.join(res))
```

[edit]: explaining the code

Observation of the data shows that the desired information on each line starts with `token '32YK1'`; what is before that is discarded.
Further analysis indicates that the last four tokens are not needed; they are excluded from the final selection.

Comment: can you please explain the code also how did the code cut off unwanted words ?

Comment: Added an explanation @e.iluf

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear what pattern you are trying to search for, assumed you want on each line the text that starts with '32YK1' and ends with 'CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE'. This allows you to find the text between those 2 wanted words

```
import re
matches = re.findall(r'32YK1.*CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE', your_string)
lines = []
for match in matches:
    lines.append(match.replace("CONTINUED ON NEXT PAGE", ""))`
```